# How to publish content to Facebook from a Windows Phone 7 device

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7

I'm writing a Windows Phone 7 App and would like to be able to push content from my app to the users facebook profile, comments, pictures etc.  I have started reading the documentation but it all talks about have a web site, which I don't have on a phone.  I think i'm missing something, really basic.   Is there away to do this with c# from a phone?

Any pointers very much appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might get some value out of SmartyP's blog post from April CTP timeframe where he put facebook's api through it's paces from WP7. He addresses the browser requirement issue.

[Using the Facebook Developer Toolkit With Windows Phone 7 | Smarty Pants Coding](http://www.smartypantscoding.com/content/using-the-facebook-developer-toolkit-with-windows-phone-7)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, this is a good demo and works for me.  Wonder why the search engines weren't picking it up.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new C# SDK for Facebook: http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/